# CodeIgniter Update Batch with Multiple Index

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, batch-updates

I'm having problem with active record Update Batch on CodeIgniter.

On the documentation,

```
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

Where 'title' is the index for the update process. Is it possible to have two or more index to this active record?
I already tried

```
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title, title_2');
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, array('title', 'title_2');
```

And it's not working.

Comment: could you explain what do you want? could you provide more codes.

Comment: I need to update batch with two indexes as the condition.
Update batch produce: ... WHEN 'title' = 'My Title' THEN 'My Name 2'... and so on. What I ask is, possibility like WHEN 'title' = 'My Title' and 'title_2' = "My Title 2" THEN 'My Name 2'. Is it clear for you?

Comment: No, its not possible to have more than one index.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply an additional `where` prior to the `update_batch`:

```php
$this->db->where( "title2", "some_title" );
$this->db->update_batch( "mytable", $data, 'title' );
```

This will then supply the `update_batch` query with the additional `WHERE`:

```sql
WHERE title2 = 'some_title' AND title IN ( '...', '...', '...' );
```

However, `update_batch` will internally reset the `WHERE` clause upon each update. So as a workaround, you can chunk this before-hand to ensure the `WHERE` is applied at each iteration:

```php
$chunks = array_chunk( $data, 100 );
foreach( $chunks as $chunk )
{
    $this->db->reset_query(); // To ensure there's no conflict/cache 
    $this->db->where( "title2", "some_title" );
    $this->db->update_batch( "mytable", $data, 'title' );
}
```